# ssh locl -> A -> B without have ssh-copy-id to B ( A can acess B )

Tags: ssh

I don't want to copy my pubkey to every remote server.

I know how to work with proxycommand

```
Host A
    HostName A
    User root
    ServerAliveInterval 240
    TCPKeepAlive yes

Host B
    HostName B
    User root
    ProxyCommand ssh root@A -W %h:%p
```

In this way, I have to copy-ssh-id to A and B .

But A have its own private key which have already copy to B. like below

```
local ssh A
A ssh B
```

I'd like to use A local pubkey to login B , not my local pubkey.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "A local pubkey"? Is that the host key, or root's ssh key? And I assume you meant "private key". Maybe it's better you show the actual problem. What happens when you `ssh` from your local host to B? What happens when you `ssh` from A to B?

Comment: Anyway, check the answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b

Comment: @aviro doesn't help , I got `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` , follow the top answer

Comment: Well, check if you have the authentication agent running. Or read the comments to this answer to check if someone else had this. Or try the other answers. There are many answers to this question, most of them upvoted. I don't mean to sound rude, but I made the effort to **google** your problem for you (something that you could have tried as well), and gave you a link that seemed useful to me. It's a problem **you're** trying to solve, so make some extra effort.

Comment: Here, read this comment to this top answer from someone who saw this exact error you wrote and googled to find the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b#comment1228634_701884 Please try to make some extra effort next time.